# R Caret createFolds uneven

Tags: r, r-caret

OK here is some test data

```
X <-  data.frame(a = seq(1,16,by=2), b = LETTERS[1:8], x= month.abb[1:8], z=letters[1:8])

y <- 1:8
```

What I'm trying to understand is how can I get createFolds to consistently create folds of the same dimensions. 
Let me give an example:

```
set.seed(233)
folds <- createFolds(y, k = 2, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)
```

output:

```
> folds
$Fold1
[1] 1 5 6 8

$Fold2
[1] 2 3 4 7
```

the second time isn't an even split of data into folds:

```
folds <- createFolds(y, k = 2, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)

> folds
$Fold1
[1] 1 2 5 7 8

$Fold2
[1] 3 4 6
```

What I would like is for an "even" division when possible every time I run the function, like in the case of 4 folds for 8 observations. In cases with its 5 folds, I understand this isn't possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - are you looking for another function that does splits this way? Are you looking for help in coding your own? What have you tried in either of those approaches and where are you stuck? There are quite a few questions about creating train/test splits...

Comment: my desire is when using createFolds more than once to have the same split of data with respect to proportion.  If I'm creating a 2 folds with 8 observations I would like 2 folds with 4 observations in each every time.  This is the case with all even observations with even folds.   I shared the code above that I'm using with test data.

Comment: `createFolds` doesn't do that.

Comment: ok, thanks, It didn't seem to do that, and after reading the docs I found no way to keep things "even" consistently. It's not a problem but an annoyance.

Comment: If you want to code your own it wouldn't be too hard. Basically, there are two common ways to do randomly assign `p` proportion of `n` observations: (a) you draw `n` random numbers and anything below `p` is assigned to the group. This is what `createFolds` does and it means that the data will be divided by that percentage *on average*. It's super efficient. (b) draw `n` random numbers, calculate the `p`th quantile, and assign all rows less than that quantile cutoff to the group. This is less efficient but will result in a consistent number of assignments to each group.

Comment: makes sense, thanks.